# Testing length of message before sending it with IBM MQ XMS API

Tags: c++, ibm-mq, xms

I am a beginner with XMS and I am having quite a hard time finding a solution to my problem. I hope you will help me find a solution or at least give me a hand.

So, in my project I am using IBM MQ XMS API to send and receive messages. It works well but there is only one problem. When the users send a message that is superior to the *Max Msg Length* it triggers a general exception. In that exception there is a treament for various case of errors but it lacks the treatments of that particular exception.

What would be the best way to test if the message length is inferior to *Max Msg Length* defined on the server before sending it? Or at least how should i catch the trigger of that exception more precisely?

(I am sorry I can't post code because it belongs to the company I am working for)

Comment: Either option is fine. Which is preferable would depend on things like how easy is it to know in advance, etc. The hard question is: what will you do if your message is too long?

Comment: If the message is too long i just want to add a warning in the log so the user understand why he lost some messages

Comment: What genetic error do you receive and what version of IBM MQ client are you using with the C++ XMS API?